# How to choose the param in fitCopula

Tags: r

Suppose I have two random variables *X*<sub>1</sub> and *X*<sub>2</sub>, both normally distributed. In R I would generate sample like this:

```
> X1 <- rnorm(1000,mean=2.4,sd=1.3)
> X2 <- rnorm(1000,mean=1.5,sd=0.9)
```

Assuming they are normally distributed with the corresponding mean and sd. My goals is to fit a copula *C* to these samples assuming a certain family for the copula *C*. For simplicity assume the bivariate distribution follows t distribution.

The first step would be to transform them into (pseudo) uniform distribution. We would look at *U*<sub>1</sub>=*F*<sub>1</sub>(*X*<sub>1</sub>) and *U*<sub>2</sub>=*F*<sub>2</sub>(*X*<sub>2</sub>). In R I would do this with the following code

```
> U1 <- pnorm(X1,mean=2.4,sd=1.3)
> U2 <- pnorm(X2,mean=1.5,sd=0.9)
```

Then I would fit a t-copula using the `copula` package. I know that I could directly fit a multivariat t distribution. However I would like to know how these things are working in the package. The function `fitCopula` needs an object of class `copula`. Obviously I would hand over a t-copula. I'm not sure how to choose the parameter, since they should be estimated. So how can I fit a t-Copula to *U*<sub>1</sub> and *U*<sub>2</sub>?

Comment: Maybe you'd better ask this question at http://datascience.stackexchange.com